# json to php (server) possible and how?

Tags: php, json, google-maps

Basically i want [this json output](http://maps.google.com/maps/nav?q=from:9500%20wil%20to:3000%20bern) to be transferred to my server/php.

i try this

```
$url="http://maps.google.com/maps/nav?q=from:9500 wil to:3000 bern";
$conte = file_get_contents($url);
echo $conte;
```

the json is not echo, how can i save the output to my server?

Comment: I get HTTP/1.0 400 Bad request with `curl -I "http://maps.google.com/maps/nav?q=from:9500 wil to:3000 bern"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `urlencode` the GET parameters:

```
echo file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/nav?q=from:9500%20wil%20to:3000%20bern');

# Returns
# {"name":"from:9500 wil to:3000 bern","Status":{"code":200,"request":"directions"},"Placemark":[{"id":"","address":"Wil, Switzerland","AddressDetails":{"Country":{"CountryNameCode":"CH","CountryName":"Schweiz","AdministrativeArea":{"AdministrativeAreaName":"St. Gallen","SubAdministrativeArea":{"SubAdministrativeAreaName":"Wil","Locality":{"LocalityName":"Wil"}}}},"Accuracy": 4},"Point":{"coordinates":[9.048081,47.463817,0]}},{"id":"","address":"Frohbergweg 7, 3012 Bern District, Switzerland","AddressDetails":{"Country":{"CountryNameCode":"CH","AdministrativeArea":{"AdministrativeAreaName":"BE","SubAdministrativeArea":{"SubAdministrativeAreaName":"Bern","Locality":{"LocalityName":"Bern District","DependentLocality":{"DependentLocalityName":"Länggasse-Felsenau","Thoroughfare":{"ThoroughfareName":"Frohbergweg 7"},"PostalCode":{"PostalCodeNumber":"3012"}}}}}},"Accuracy": 0},"Point":{"coordinates":[7.436386,46.954897,0]}}],"Directions":{"copyrightsHtml":"Map data \u0026#169;2010 Google, Tele Atlas ","summaryHtml":"178\u0026nbsp;km (about 2 hours 2 mins)","Distance":{"meters":177791,"html":"178\u0026nbsp;km"},"Duration":{"seconds":7343,"html":"2 hours 2 mins"},"Routes":[{"Distance":{"meters":177791,"html":"178\u0026nbsp;km"},"Duration":{"seconds":7343,"html":"2 hours 2 mins"},"summaryHtml":"178\u0026nbsp;km (about 2 hours 2 mins)","Steps":[{"descriptionHtml":"Head \u003Cb\u003Esouth\u003C\/b\u003E on \u003Cb\u003EToggenburgerstrasse\u003C\/b\u003E toward \u003Cb\u003ELerchenfeldstrasse\/\u003Cwbr\/\u003ERoute 16\/\u003Cwbr\/\u003ERoute 7\u003C\/b\u003E","Distance":{"meters":29,"html":"29\u0026nbsp;m"},"Duration":{"seconds":2,"html":"2 secs"},"Point":{"coordinates":[9.048030,47.463830,0]}},{"descriptionHtml":"Take the 1st left onto \u003Cb\u003ERoute 7\u003C\/b\u003E","Distance":{"meters":625,"html":"650\u0026nbsp;m"},"Duration":{"seconds":109,"html":"2 mins"},"Point":{"coordinates":[9.047930,47.463570,0]}},{"descriptionHtml":"At the traffic circle, take the \u003Cb\u003E1st\u003C\/b\u003E exit onto \u003Cb\u003EGeorg Rennerstrasse\u003C\/b\u003E","Distance":{"meters":871,"html":"850\u0026nbsp;m"},"Duration":{"seconds":77,"html":"1 min"},"Point":{"coordinates":[9.056170,47.463110,0]}},{"descriptionHtml":"Take the ramp to \u003Cb\u003EZürich\/\u003Cwbr\/\u003EFrauenfeld\u003C\/b\u003E","Distance":{"meters":330,"html":"350\u0026nbsp;m"},"Duration":{"seconds":22,"html":"22 secs"},"Point":{"coordinates":[9.053350,47.455800,0]}},{"descriptionHtml":"Merge onto \u003Cb\u003EA1\u003C\/b\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\"google_impnote\"\u003EToll road\u003C\/div\u003E","Distance":{"meters":173696,"html":"174\u0026nbsp;km"},"Duration":{"seconds":6790,"html":"1 hour 53 mins"},"Point":{"coordinates":[9.050270,47.453900,0]}},{"descriptionHtml":"Take exit \u003Cb\u003E36-Bern-Neufeld\u003C\/b\u003E toward \u003Cb\u003EBremgarten\u003C\/b\u003E","Distance":{"meters":579,"html":"600\u0026nbsp;m"},"Duration":{"seconds":33,"html":"33 secs"},"Point":{"coordinates":[7.436980,46.966570,0]}},{"descriptionHtml":"At the traffic circle, take the \u003Cb\u003E2nd\u003C\/b\u003E exit onto \u003Cb\u003ENeubrückstrasse\u003C\/b\u003E","Distance":{"meters":1357,"html":"1.4\u0026nbsp;km"},"Duration":{"seconds":243,"html":"4 mins"},"Point":{"coordinates":[7.429580,46.966790,0]}},{"descriptionHtml":"Turn right at \u003Cb\u003EMittelstrasse\u003C\/b\u003E","Distance":{"meters":146,"html":"150\u0026nbsp;m"},"Duration":{"seconds":24,"html":"24 secs"},"Point":{"coordinates":[7.437750,46.956720,0]}},{"descriptionHtml":"Take the 1st left onto \u003Cb\u003EBrückfeldstrasse\u003C\/b\u003E","Distance":{"meters":104,"html":"100\u0026nbsp;m"},"Duration":{"seconds":33,"html":"33 secs"},"Point":{"coordinates":[7.436060,46.956100,0]}},{"descriptionHtml":"Take the 1st right onto \u003Cb\u003EFrohbergweg\u003C\/b\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\"google_note\"\u003EDestination will be on the left\u003C\/div\u003E","Distance":{"meters":54,"html":"54\u0026nbsp;m"},"Duration":{"seconds":10,"html":"10 secs"},"Point":{"coordinates":[7.436830,46.955320,0]}}],"End":{"coordinates":[7.436234,46.955057,0]}}]}}
```

Comment: +1. I figured it out as I edited the OP, so I posted it anyway with my answer. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @alex - No problem, i was also reaching for the fopen URL wrappers at first when I tried curl, and it didn't work either - It had to be the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

How do you want to save it? As a file?

If you can open via `file_get_contents()`, then URL opening for `fopen()` wrappers is on.

Then you can just do...

```
$url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/nav?q=from:9500 wil to:3000 bern';

$content = file_get_contents($url);

file_put_contents('google-map-json.txt', $content);
```

You can get that into a usable object in PHP with `json_decode()`.

You may want to do that if you want to save it to your database.

If you don't want to overwrite the file each time, you could generate a random hash of the response for the filename, or something similar.

#### Update

> sorry my bad. i know how to save file. but the json is not even echoed through file_get_contents.

You may not have URL `fopen()` wrappers enabled.

You can find out by running this...

```
var_dump(ini_get('allow_url_fopen'));
```

If it is disabled, and you can't or don't want to turn it on, you can use cURL (if you have that library installed).

#### Update

When I tried to access the page via `file_get_contents()`, I got...

> HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request

You may need to use cURL, and mimic a browser (user agent etc).

Or you can set

```
ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla or something');
```

And then use `file_get_contents()`.

#### Update

I tried with cURL too, and it didn't work  :(

I think the next step is to examine all the headers your browser sends (when it works), and then send the equivalent via cURL.

#### Update

I noticed the Markdown editor wasn't liking the URL ([see my OP's edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4388127/revisions)), and it dawned me - `urlencode()` the GET params!

Comment: sorry my bad. i know how to save file. but the json is not even echoed through file_get_contents.

Comment: im on hostgator so it works. but the code does not work, try it yourself. i can't write or echo that output with php. i would know how to do with Javascript but thats not the question.

Comment: @Email Hmm, the URL fetching works for me on my Hostgator account. What does `var_dump(file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/nav?q=from:9500 wil to:3000 bern'))` output? Is it possible they block user agents, or your IP? Has it worked in the past? What did that update code output above?

Comment: thx 4your help. it really was the urlencode like jwandborg stated. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can write the data to a file using PHP's IO functions

```
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $conte);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: the file is empty since even the echoing of that data fails.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to parse the data from the [file_get_contents()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) variable. (I would personally use [cURL](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) instead of [file_get_contents()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)).